How to Apply External CSS Styles to HTML Content in Flutter?
I'm working on a Flutter project where I need to render HTML content received from a backend API, and I have an external CSS file stored locally. I'm struggling to integrate the external CSS file into the HTML code to apply styles to the rendered content.
Background:
I have HTML data fetched from a backend API, stored in a string variable.
I also have an external CSS file named "styles.css" stored locally in my Flutter project directory.
Issue:
Despite trying various approaches, I'm unable to apply the styles from the CSS file to the HTML content in Flutter. I've attempted to embed the CSS styles within the HTML content using the  tag, but I'm not sure how to reference the external CSS file.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';

class HtmlPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var htmlContent = '''<blockquote class="ql-align-right"><span class="ql-size-huge">this is </span><span class="ql-size-huge" style="color: rgb(102, 185, 102);">c</span><span class="ql-size-huge"> </span><span class="ql-size-huge" style="color: rgb(230, 0, 0);">aligned</span></blockquote><blockquote class="ql-align-right"><span class="ql-size-huge">this is </span><span class="ql-size-huge" style="color: rgb(102, 185, 102);">r</span><span class="ql-size-huge"> </span><span class="ql-size-huge" style="color: rgb(230, 0, 0);">aligned</span></blockquote><blockquote><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" class="ql-size-huge">this is </span><span style="color: rgb(102, 185, 102);" class="ql-size-huge">l</span><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"> </span><span style="color: rgb(230, 0, 0);" class="ql-size-huge">aligned</span></blockquote>''';



    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Render HTML with External CSS'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: HtmlWidget('''
     <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
        </head>
        <body>
       $htmlContent
         </body>
      </html>
      '''),
      ),
    );
  }
}


is it possible, at this way ? Please help, Thanks
